# Run Python API script from cron

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to run Python script for API. When I run it manualy it works fine. When I try to run the same script using cron, it fails.

In cron job i've something like this:

```
0 8-17     * * * root  /usr/bin/python3 /root/scripts/python_script.sh
```

I've tryied also to run Python script from bash script, and manually it works, but running bash script with Python inside via cron doesn't work.

I think that problem is with saving file in my script, but i can't figured it out.

My Python script for API is below:

```
import requests
import json
import shutil
import os
import glob

def main():


    ses = requests.Session()
    base_url = 'URL/auth'
    headers = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
    payload = {'username':'USER', 'password':'PASS'}

    response = ses.post(base_url, data=payload, headers=headers)
    cookieJar = ses.cookies


    s = str(cookieJar)


    base_url_export = 'URL/export'
    headers_export = {'accept':'application/json', 'Cookie':get_cookies, 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    payload_export = {'names':'FILE_1'}

    response_export_route = ses.post(base_url_export, data=json.dumps(payload_export), headers=headers_export)

    file_download_FILE_1 = str(response_export_FILE_1.text)
    


    file_request = ses.get("URL/getFile/"+file_download_FILE_1)
    open(file_download_FILE_1+".xlsx", "wb").write(file_request.content)

    shutil.move('/root/scripts/'+file_download_FILE_1+'.xlsx', 'DST-DIR')
```

Comment: Hm... Where are You actually calling `main` function?

Comment: It doesn't work? That says very little. What is the error? Do you get any output?

Comment: i figured it OUT
i just forget to change DIR for run python script.